# rows and columns in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I am trying to show 'test' name 3 times in a row and 3 times in the second row but it's not showing me the sections in a horizontal row

Instead, it showing me everything in verticle col pattern...

```
    <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
<title>bootstrap</title>
```

```
<div class="services container">
    <h2>Services</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <section class="col-md-6 col-md-4">
            <img class="icon" src='images/cabbage.png' alt="Icon">
            <h3>Vegitables</h3>
            <p>Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size increases. It includes predefined classes for easy layout options, as well as powerful mixins for generating more semantic layouts.</p>
        </section>
        <section class="col-md-6 col-md-4">
            <img class="icon" src='images/car.png' alt="Icon">
            <h3>Cars</h3>
            <p>Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size increases. It includes predefined classes for easy layout options, as well as powerful mixins for generating more semantic layouts.</p>
        </section>
        <section class="col-md-6 col-md-4">
            <img class="icon" src='images/clothes.png' alt="Icon">
            <h3>clothss</h3>
            <p>Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size increases. It includes predefined classes for easy layout options, as well as powerful mixins for generating more semantic layouts.</p>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <section class="col-md-6 col-md-4">
            <img class="icon" src='images/motorcycle.png' alt="Icon">
            <h3>Motorcycle</h3>
            <p>Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size increases. It includes predefined classes for easy layout options, as well as powerful mixins for generating more semantic layouts.</p>
        </section>
        <section class="col-md-6 col-md-4">
            <img class="icon" src='images/pet-icon.png' alt="Icon">
            <h3>Pets</h3>
            <p>Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size increases. It includes predefined classes for easy layout options, as well as powerful mixins for generating more semantic layouts.</p>
        </section>
        <section class="col-md-6 col-md-4">
            <img class="icon" src='images/phone.png' alt="Icon">
            <h3>Phone</h3>
            <p>
                    Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size increases. It includes predefined classes for easy layout options, as well as powerful mixins for generating more semantic layouts.
            </p>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

```
//my css code

    .icon{
        max-width: 150px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
    }
    .service section{
        text-align: center;
    }
```

how this code will work? are there some corrections or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap grid system requires their css styles.

Try putting the following in your `<head>` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Your code seems fine, it should work after that.

Comment: but it will take css from online , but i want to import from offline css. so what should i do??

Comment: If you're not interested in using a content delivery network (totally fine), you can bring Bootstrap in locally by downloading it [here](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/). After that, just set your href path to point to where your bootstrap's css is located. 

If you're looking for a more advanced option, you can also look to import it with NPM which will make for a better development experience. For now though, I think you'll be okay with just downloading bootstrap locally.

Comment: Note that the above link is for Bootstrap 4. If you're looking for Bootstrap 3, which you were using in your code above, then click [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/).

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct, you just need to handle for multiple screen resolutions, with the below snippet i added `col-xs-4` which gives me the ability to render my grid system on smaller screens, checkout bootstrap's grid system's options [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-options) that should help you

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <div class="container">//main container
            <h2>Services</h2>
            <div class="row">//1st row
                <section class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-md-6">
                    <h2>Test</h2>
                </section>
                <section class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-md-6">
                    <h2>Test</h2>
                </section>
                <section class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-md-6">
                    <h2>Test</h2>
                </section>
            </div>
            <div class="row">//2nd row
                <section class="col-md-4">
                    <h2>Test</h2>
                </section>
                <section class="col-md-4">
                    <h2>Test</h2>
                </section>
                <section class="col-md-4">
                    <h2>Test</h2>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: @AkshayDeshpande but with the `run code snippet` its working right? because i just did locally and it's working

Comment: Cool , you simply mark as answer @AkshayDeshpande thanks